# Why is handler script not found in this AWS Lambda deployment package?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, localstack

Following is the `golang` sample lambda function from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/golang-handler.html :

```
$ cat ./foo.go
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "context"
  "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
)

type MyEvent struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
}

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, name MyEvent) (string, error) {
  return fmt.Sprintf("Hello %s!", name.Name ), nil
}

func main() {
  lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
```

I believe I've correctly followed the steps to create a deployment package:

```
$ GOOS=linux go build foo.go
$ zip foo.zip foo
  adding: foo (deflated 49%)
$
```

**What is wrong with the above lambda function or deployment package? If nothing, why does the lambda create-function fail with an inability to find a handler script?**

```
$ aws --profile jack --endpoint-url http://localhost:4574 lambda create-function --function-name foo --runtime go1.x --zip-file fileb://foo.zip --handler main --role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/lambda-role

An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateFunction operation: Unable to find handler script (/tmp/localstack/zipfile.07e4ae91/main) in Lambda archive. Config for local mount, docker, remote: "False", "True", "True"
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the following github issues and PRs:

- [Support for golang lambda functions](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/issues/561)
- [Add golang support to lambda](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/pull/617)

There might be special steps required to enable/use the go in localstack.